# Input validation with Jquery-validaton v1.19.3 + Bootstrap v4.6 in Symfony v5.2 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, bootstrap-4, jquery-validate

### INTRODUCTION

I am using `Bootstrap v4.6`, `jQuery v3.5.1` and `jquery-validation v1.19.3`, in `Symfony v5.2` project to validate user inputs.

### EXPECTATION

I would like the validation to look the same - eather with JavaScript or PHP.

### STEPS TAKEN

For that i took an example [jquery-validation on GitHub](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/2170#issuecomment-392618183)

I followed the example - yet part of error message stays on screen.

[image]

### EXAMPLE

I creted jsfiddle to present the problem: [Examle on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onrc9de1/36/).

Check by writing a name that is *less than 3* or *more than 25* characters long.

### CODE

```
{
    let $app_locale = $('html')[0].lang;

    jQuery.validator.setDefaults(
    {
        lang: $app_locale,
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function(error, element)
        {
            let customError = $([
                '<span class="invalid-feedback mt-0 mb-2 d-block">',
                '  <span class="error-box mb-0 d-block">',
                '    <span class="form-error-icon badge badge-danger text-uppercase">Error</span>',
                '  </span>',
                '</span>'
            ].join(""));

            // Add `form-error-message` class to the error element
            error.addClass("form-error-message");

            // Insert it inside the span that has `mb-0` class
            error.appendTo(customError.find('.error-box'));

            // Insert your custom error
            customError.insertBefore(element);
        },
        highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass)
        {
            $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
            $(element).closest('.invalid-feedback').toggle();
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass)
        {
            $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
            $(element).closest('.invalid-feedback').toggle();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is simply not finding the `.invalid-feedback` because it is not an ancestor of `element` which is the `<input>` element. Also, your selector `('.invalid-feedback')` is insufficient to hide the nested `.error-box.d-block`.

This appears to work well:

```
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span').show();
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
        $(element).closest('.form-group').find('span').hide();
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/9k0L285d/